# Sharepoint Multiline Values on Load

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to capture all of the fields of a SharePoint form using JavaScript during the initial load of the edit form. Somehow, only the first two multi-line fields are being captured properly. When I change the order of the fields this works. For example:
Field 1
Field 2
Field 3

Fields 1 & 2 are captured.

If I change the order they appear:
Field 2
Field 3
Field 1

Fields 2 & 3 are captured.

This doesn't appear to be affected by the code itself, but something to do with loading in SharePoint. But here is the code anyways:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
if(document.readyState === 'complete')
{
    getFields();
    getValues();
    var myStatement =  $("textarea[Title='Problem Statement']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").contents().text();
    var myScope =  $("textarea[Title='Scope']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").contents().text();
}
});
```

I am also using SPUtility to capture values and am having difficult getting support elsewhere.

SPUtility code:

```
scope = SPUtility.GetSPField('Scope');
scopeVal = scope.GetValue();
```

All of the fields are being captured per the above code in getFields() and getValues() called in the above code during window.load.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Every field is embedded in a `<td>` that contains the following HTML comment:

```
<!-- FieldName="Field1"
         FieldInternalName="Field1"
         FieldType="SPFieldNote"
      -->
```

While you can't explicitly query the DOM for this comment, you can query to get all the fields on the form and then loop through them, checking their innerHTML property to see if they contain the desired comment string.

By this means, you can determine the exact parent `<td>` element for any desired field. This allows you to be more precise than by using jQuery's `.closest()` function.

The other thing to keep in mind is that enhanced rich text, rich text, and plain text multiline fields are each rendered differently, and will thus require different query selector parameters to obtain their values.

The following example code gets the values of multiline fields with internal names of Field1, Field2, or Field3, and stores the values in an object.

```
var richTextFieldNames = ["Field1","Field2","Field3"];
var richTextFieldValues = {};
var fieldRows = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-formtable td.ms-formbody");
for(var i = 0, len = richTextFieldNames.length; i<len; i++){
    currentFieldName = richTextFieldNames[i];
    for(var j = 0, jlen = fieldRows.length; j<jlen; j++){
        var currentRow = fieldRows[j];
        if(currentRow.innerHTML.indexOf("FieldInternalName=\""+currentFieldName+"\"") > -1){
            var element = currentRow.querySelector(".ms-rtestate-field[role=\"textbox\"]"); // enhanced rich text
            if(!element){
                var iframe = currentRow.querySelector("iframe[title=\"Rich Text Editor\"]");
                if(iframe){
                    element = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector("body"); // rich text
                }else{
                    element = currentRow.querySelector("textarea"); // plain text
                }
            }
            richTextFieldValues[currentFieldName] = element.innerText ? element.innerText : element.textContent;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The values can then be accessed as properties of the `richTextFieldValues` object by using array or dot notation, e.g. `var myScope = richTextFieldValues["Scope"];` or `richTextFieldValues.Scope;` (assuming Scope is the internal name of a multi-line field).

Comment: Ok, so this is working as expected, except when I try to call the values in `richTextFieldValues`, with either of the two methods you mentioned, I get undefined. Actually, I'm using `displayVal = richTextFieldValues["\"" + currentFieldName + "\""];`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... Let's check what values are stored in `richTextFieldValues` using `JSON.stringify` as follows: `alert(JSON.stringify(richTextFieldValues));`

Comment: This results in: {"FieldName1":"FieldName1Value","FieldName2":"FieldName2Value"}. There are seven fields. So I am running into the same issue of only capturing the first two fields. This only happens on page load, I have a PreSaveAction() function and it captures all values perfectly.

Comment: Instead of running your code in jQuery's `load` function, you could try delaying its execution until after SharePoint has finished loading. For example, `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){ /* your code here */ },"sp.js");`

Comment: Ok, so I realized I hadn't tested this in anything other than IE. I tried it in Firefox and it works. I have IE11, but due to compatibility issues it's set to run in IE8 mode. Any ideas on how to get this to work in an older browser?